# CHA_FAN Stoped giving power to fan

Tags: power-management, fan

My chassis fan stopped spinning after a reinstall of Windows 7 32bit today.  I did spend quite a bit of time trying to tweak power management settings, however I've reverted all to default and still I cannot get my chassis fan to work while in windows any longer.

Pre-reinstall, it worked fine, even when the computer was in sleep mode.  Now, no longer.  When I reboot, and BIOS has control of the board, the fan spins up.  As soon as Windows loads, it shuts off.  This is going to cause a huge problem as I've got a fanless video card (AMD HD 6450), which got up to 108C due to no moving air.

MB:  Asus P8H67M-LE
OS:  Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit

Those are the only relevant pieces of info I can think of.

Comment: could you try with a Linux (i.e. Ubuntu) live CD and see if the fan spins up?

Comment: Hold on, your chassis fan worked **when in sleep mode**?  That is *not* normal behaviour.  Also, by default, Windows 7 should not be managing *any* of your fans (AFAIK, no default drivers come with that ability).  Have you installed any third-party (AKA non-Microsoft) drivers or applications since the format?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download a fan-speed managing software like: [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and check to see if you can force the FAN into working by tweaking the settings using that software.

If you still can't get it to work, you're goign to have to sift through the power-savings settings in Windows until you find where you disabled the fan. Also, make sure that you're running "Maximum Performance" mode all the time on a desktop machine.